# Повторная установка ant

Tags: apache, ant, unix, solaris, linux

Я действовал согласно [Installing Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html) повторно, потому что не выдает версию ant - ant -version. Ввел следующие 3 команды

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/apache-ant-1.8.4  
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_06
export export PATH=${PATH}:${ANT_HOME}/bin
```

После ввода последней команды я получил

> bash:export:
> [1m/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:
>
> /usr/gcc/4.4/bin=/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
>
> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/gcc/4.4/bin:/usr/apache-ant-1.8.4/bin [0m:
>
> not a valid identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` не нашел в пути исполняемый скрипт `ant`

Скрипт `%ANT_HOME%/bin/ant` надо сделать исполняемым:

```
$ chmod u+x %ANT_HOME%/bin/ant
```